# object at 0x03885A90> API requst

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

When requesting the balance of my account via an api i get the reply `<huobi.model.account.Account object at 0x00B15A90>]>` instead of a float. Can i convert this to the balance or do anything with this?

API : Python_Huobi
Code:

```py
request_client = RequestClient(api_key="X", secret_key="X")

btcbalance= request_client.get_account_balance()
print(btcbalance)
```

Comment: What is `RequestClient`? Which API are you calling? There's not enough to go on to help you with this. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `btcbalance` is an instance of an `Account` class. You can inspect the methods and attributes on that class with `dir(btcbalance)` or `help(btcbalance)`

Comment: Well try it out and the api is https://github.com/huobiapi/huobi_Python

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `object.__dict__` attribute of any object to get all its attributes and their values in a dict. You could change your code to:

```
request_client = RequestClient(api_key="X", secret_key="X")

btcbalance = request_client.get_account_balance()
print(btcbalance.__dict__)
```

Then you can get the name of the attribute that holds your balance. You can then access it with `btcbalance.balance` (if balance is the name of the right attribute).

Comment: Thank you this helped me getting 1 step closer to the solution. Now i get the error message "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__dict__'" do you know how to fix this? Also thank you again for helping me out